# Mocking a function/object, and return values based on input/conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

I am facing the following scenario.

I have the following source code

```py
#file:[src/my_module.py]

def order_names(unordered_input: List) -> str: 
   # function that orders a list of names
   ...
       if(is_ID(unordered_input[i])):
           id = unordered_input[i]
           name = get_name_by_id(id)
   ...

def get_name_by_id(id) -> str: 
   # function that returns a name, based on an ID, through a Rest API call
   return make_some_network_call(id)
```

I want to test the function `order_names`, and I want to mock the calls to `get_name_by_id(id)`.

Assuming that the `get_name_by_id(id)` will be called many times for various `id`s, can a mock be created that returns values according to the input?

For example:

```py
#file:[test/test_my_module.py]
from unittest import mock
from my_module import order_names

@mock.patch("src.my_module.get_name_by_id", return_value={"3": "Mark", "4": "Kate", "5":"Alfred"})
def test_order_names():
   ordered_names = order_names(["3", "4", "Suzan", "5"])
   assert ordered_names == "Alfred, Kate, Mark, Suzan"
```

The above test code is an example of the type of the behavior to be achieved, since `get_name_by_id()` is not a `dict` return type.

Cheers!

Comment: `get_name_by_id` is supposed to return a name; mocking it to return a `dict` won't help. What I think you *really* want to mock is `make_some_network_call`, so that `get_name_by_id` continues to work as-is.

Comment: @chepner Exactly. The patch code I provided, is just an example of a desired outcome. Let me elaborate, as I can see this can create confusion.

Comment: I'll backpedal a little as well; there might be reasons for patching `get_name_by_id` entirely rather than patching something it uses.

Comment: @chepner Can you please elaborate. I have the believe that this is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need an alternate implementation of `get_name_by_id`, not just a new return value.

```
# Adjust the definition to behave the same when the lookup fails
def get_name_locally(id):
    return {"3": "Mark", "4": "Kate", "5":"Alfred"}.get(id)


def test_order_names():
    with mock.patch('src.my_module.get_name_by_id', get_name_locally):
        ordered_names = order_names(["3", "4", "Suzan", "5"])
    assert ordered_names = "Alfred, Kate, Mark, Suzan"
```

---

If `get_name_by_id` is more complicated, you could also consider patching the network call instead and letting `get_name_by_id` run as-is.

```
# The same as get_name_locally above, but only because
# get_name_by_id and make_some_network_call are functionally
# identical as far as the question is written.
def network_replacement(id):
    return {"3": "Mark", "4": "Kate", "5":"Alfred"}.get(id)


def test_order_names():
    with mock.patch('src.my_module.make_some_network_call', network_replacement):
        ordered_names = order_names(["3", "4", "Suzan", "5"])
    assert ordered_names = "Alfred, Kate, Mark, Suzan"
```

Now when you call `order_names`, and it calls `get_name_by_id`, your alternate definition of `make_some_network_call` will be used by `get_name_by_id`.

Comment: Can the network call be patched in a way, that will provide different results for the various input `id`s?

Comment: Yes. Given that you could have initially defined `get_name_by_id = make_some_network_call`, you can use the same `get_name_locally`, just patching a different name. Essentially, you are just replacing whatever database exists over the network with a local `dict`.